# PHP 5.6 mcrypt.so extension in El Capitan

Tags: php, mcrypt

I've installed mcrypt and mcrypt-php5.6 on el capitan with homebrew with

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt
brew install mcrypt
```

and `mcrypt -v` shows me

```
Mcrypt v.0.9.9 (i386-apple-darwin15.0.0)
Linked against libmcrypt v.2.5.8
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 Nikos Mavroyanopoulos (nmav@gnutls.org)
```

but when I try to create new laravel project I get

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Also as  `php_info()` represents,  mcrypt installed completely but I have gotten the top error in composer.

Comment: `mcrypt` extension appears to be abandoned and it's full of bugs. May I suggest you use PHP's `openssl` for encryption / decryption purposes and [the following library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) that plays along with it?